# Freeing jni references from memory

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk, arrays

I create a byte array in java and pass it by reference to the jni function. This I do in a loop and and sometimes get a out of memory error in the jni. I wanted to know if java automatically frees the array on every iteration or since it is passed to the jni function, it doesn't ??

JNI Code     (bOldArray is the java byte array that i pass to jni as an argument)

```
len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,bOldArray);
char *oldBuff = (char *)calloc(sizeof(char),MAX_SIZE);
jbyte* bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,bOldArray,0);
memcpy(oldBuff,bytes,len);
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env,bOldArray,(jbyte *)bytes,0);
```

Comment: Still cant seem to find the error.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 buffers here, one handed from your java code (bOldArray)and the local buffer (oldbuff) which you allocated in line 2.

in fact, you might have more buffers, because

```
(*env)->GetArrayLength
```

with almost certainly makes a unmovable copy of the memory (needed for c-pointer-access), which holds the array in you java code and with

```
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env,bOldArray,(jbyte *)bytes,0);
```

this memory is copied back onto the memory of your java array (check documentation of the last argument of ReleaseByteArrayElements)

**but about you problem:** you should free oldBuff too.

```
free(oldBuff);
```

else the VM does free your c-copy of the java array but not the self-allocated part directly (it might do thiz later due to object-lifetime and garbage collection, but this is unpredictable and therefore the out-of-memory error is also unpredictable)

to avoid the java-c-copy mechanism (speeds up performance) use a shared/static buffer like ByteBuffer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GetByteArrayElements` you have to call `ReleaseByteArrayElements` after you are done with the array in JNI, because the JVM will prevent the freeing of this array in java until you do so.
Please post the code to get a clearer idea

Comment: Looks like the release of the java array is being done fine. Couple of suggestions.You can calloc using len instead of MAX_SIZE. Also, if this function is being called in a loop, you will have to release the oldBuff at some point

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Yes I am freeing oldBuff before returning to jni.

Comment: Just to clarify, when  you call this JNI function from java in a loop, you are still getting a OutOfMemory ? Is this the only code required to get the OutOfMemory? Also do you get an OutOfMemoryError as an Error thrown from Java, or is it being seen from native code, when a calloc fails?

Comment: yeah i get out of memory. Yes it is the only code it is being seen by native code when calloc fails

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine, as long as you are sure that you free it properly. Try and make sure that you are always freeing the oldBuff, before calloc again. Cant think of anything else, unless you post the full code